# Extract a link from a webpage using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I have this problem: I want to extract the URL of each single project from this page, but I don't know how to do that. I tried to extract it through

```
projects = main_page.find_all_next('div', attrs={'class':'relative self-start'})
```

but I don't get the link. How can I go through it? Thank you in advance for helping me.

[image]

Comment: It might help if you add the code block. So we see the hole set up and imports etc used. Are you sure the dynamically loaded content, is already available?

Answer (score 0):

This website dynamically loaded content. So you need something that can run javascript. There is an easy example to access site with selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/music"

dr = webdriver.Chrome() # or PhantomJS,Firefox
try:
    dr.get(url)
    main_page = BeautifulSoup(dr.page_source,"lxml")
    projects = main_page.find_all('div', {'class':'relative self-start'})
    project_showed = main_page.find_all("div",class_="bg-white black relative border-grey-500 border")
    print(len(projects))
except Exception as e:
    raise e

finally:
    dr.close()
```

But if you can not load data in time, you should use `WebDriverWait` or `Implicit` to wait for it loading finished. [WebDriverWait and Implicit](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Answer (score 0):

the link generated by javascript, you can't get it with BeutifulSoup, use `Regex` to capture url in javascript variable

```
import requests
import re

html = requests.get('https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/music').text
listURL = re.findall(r'"project":"([^"]+)', html)
for url in listURL:
    print url
```

Comment: Through this steps I don't get the links that I want, but I get random ones. I want the link of each single project from this webpage:https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?category_id=16&raised=2&sort=most_funded&seed=2569487&page=1

Comment: its not random but return first 24 project url, you need to extract json with endpoint `.../advanced?param....` to get more results or see this lib https://github.com/Dansc/pykick